# Show ViewBag message for some seconds then redirect to another action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, redirecttoaction

I have an Action Method that sets a message to `ViewBag` and returns to the HomePage, like,

```
 ViewBag.errormsg = "Some Temporary message";
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
```

As per this approach User won't be able to see the `ViewBag.errormsg` in that page, Because it redirects to Dashboard immediately, But I want to show That message for 1 to 2 second then after redirect to dashboard.

I have tried using `Task.WaitAll();` method to delay the call for `RedirectToAction` like here,

```
ViewBag.errormsg = "Some Temporary message";
Task.WaitAll(Task.Delay(2000));
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
```

But it's fairly a silly work, that ViewBag won't show message until the return method is called, Is there any simple way to accomplish this ?

I think `TempData` is not suitable in my case because I don't want to show that ViewBag Message to HomePage, It should be shown in the current page.

Comment: The only way to stay on the same page is to use ajax. (there is no point putting anything in `ViewBag` then redirecting - its immediately lost)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can I redirect (immediately or after some delay) to another page in some response with the help of Ajax and Jquery ?

Comment: You can make an ajax call, get a response to update the existing page and use a javascirpt timer to redirect after 2 seconds, but why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a request that user enters something, If it's correct then I want to show some Message on the same page and then redirect to homepage, I can show the message in homepage using TempData but It won't looks better, It should be shown in the same page, Then redirect to homepage.

Comment: Then make an ajax call. But it sounds like you validating something, in which case use a validation attribute.

Comment: It's not validation, It's the case of changing the password, If changed then Show password changed successfully and then redirect to homepage, I will try ajax as well. Thank you very much for your time. Can you please suggest what would you do in this kind of situations ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that? If its successful, the user is redirected and they know it was successful. If not, then you return the view with an error message so they know its not.

Comment: @StephenMuecke hehe, That's right, But I thought it's better informing that password has been changed, If its so, I'll leave it as it is, Until another requirements, Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do that on the server side, you'll have to use javascript.

You can use:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
window.location.href='your URL';
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what process that you want to do:

`Controller => Current view => Redirect => Dashboard view`

First, include your message in current view:

```
ViewBag.errormsg = "Some Temporary message";
return View("CurrentView");
```

Set an HTML element to show that message and use JS timeout on current CSHTML view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onMessageShow() {
    var msg = "@ViewBag.errormsg";
    // if the message exists, set redirection to dashboard page
    if (msg != null || typeof msg !== "undefined") {
         setTimeout('redirect', 5000); // 5 seconds for example
    }
}

function redirect() {
    window.location.href = "@Url.Content("Index", "Dashboard")";
    // or use window.location.replace, depending what your need
}
</script>

<html>
<body onload="onMessageShow()">
    <!-- simplified for brevity -->
    <p>@ViewBag.errormsg</p>
    <!-- simplified for brevity -->
</body>
</html>
```

`Task.WaitAll` with `Task.Delay` used together in server-side to delay execution of server-side process (including `async` processes), in your case there are client-side events which redirecting to index page after message appears.

CMIIW.